# Mesclar uma feature com vários commits ao longo do tempo em outro projeto

Tags: git

Tem uma feature `tenis` com vários commits ao longo do tempo, e preciso mesclar essa feature em **outro** projeto.

Considere esta linha do tempo:

```
- x - tenisV1 - x - x - tenisV2 - x - tenisV3 - x - x - x - x - x - tenisV4
```

Eu quero:

```
- tenisV1 - tenisV2 - tenisV3 - tenisV4
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Estava pensando em exibir o `diff` de todos esses commits mesclados pra me ajudar, mas não sei como fazer isso sem mostrar alterações de commits não relacionados no meio da linha do tempo (*commits x*).

Estou usando git e também bitbucket então se tiver algo visual lá seria legal também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando **cherry-pick**. Você escolhe os commits que deseja e traz eles pra branch que está.

No commit que você deseja replicar faça

```
- git log
```

A resposta será algo assim:

```
- "9ce8fa5a3d3a3555222eabb234df93cc5447####"
```

O resultado será o ID do commit, copie-o, faça um checkout pra sua nova feature.

```
- git checkout "nome da branch".
- git cherry-pick "9ce8fa5a3d3a3555222eabb234df93cc5447####"
```

Repita o processo para todos os commit em ordem.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @MarcelFelipe

É possível também usar o cherry-pick com vários commits caso eles estejam em ordem, por exemplo, considere os commits A - B - C - D, sendo A mais velho e D o mais novo:

```
git checkout branch-destino
git cherry-pick A^..D
```

Observação: `^` serve para incluir também o commit A

Caso a ordem esteja bagunçada, o comando irá falhar silenciosamente, [fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933416/2312615).